# Math domain error in python when using log

Tags: python, math, logarithm

Here is what I am writing:

```
>>> import math
>>> 2/3*math.log(2/3,2)
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: `(2/3)* math.log(2,2)/math.log(3,2)` will work

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming this is Python 2.7.

In 2.7, 2/3 evaluates to 0 since division floors by default. Therefore you're attempting a log 0, hence the error. Python 3 on the other hand does floating point division by default.

To get the correct behaviour you can either:

1. `from __future__ import division`, which gives you Python 3 division behaviour in Python 2.7.
2. Replace each `2/3` with `2/float(3)`, or `2/3.0`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are probably using python 2.7. In this version 2/3 gives as result 0 (zero). And log function is not defined for 0. Try this:

```
2/3.0*math.log(2/3.0,2)
```

In Python 3.5 this problem does not happen.

Comment: This explains it. Thank you so much!