# ValueError: math domain error in python2

Tags: python, math

when I run this code:

```
max(MIN_LEARNING_RATE, min(0.5, 1.0 - math.log10((t+1)/25)))
```

with `t = 0`

I've this error:

```
ValueError: math domain error
```

but if i run the same code with python 3.6 the error disappeared

Comment: Python 2 does integer division, so `0 / 25` will be `0`. Use `(t+1)/25.0` to force calculation with a floating point result..

Comment: If `t` is an int, `(t+1)/25` is floor-division on Python 2. That's probably giving you 0.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015253/math-domain-error-in-python-when-using-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to rounding in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), `(0+1)/25` evaluates to `1/25`, which rounds to `0`. Thus, `math.log10(0)`, which is undefined, results in a `ValueError`.

Either add `from __future__ import division` to the **first line in your program** or change the line of code to `max(MIN_LEARNING_RATE, min(0.5, 1.0 - math.log10((t+1)/25.0)))`

Comment: with 25.0 i resolved, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's because in Python 2, the division returns a floor of the float, and in the case where it's `1/25`, it returns 0.

And `math.log(0)` gives a domain error.

So in your Python 2 code, add this at the start of the script:

```
from __future__ import division
```

---

**By default in Python 2**:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 18 2016, 07:03:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.log(1/25)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
>>> 1/25
0
```

**In Python 3**:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr  4 2017, 09:40:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.log(1/25)
-3.2188758248682006
>>> 1/25
0.04
```

**In Python 2 with `__future__.division`**:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 18 2016, 07:03:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> import math
>>> math.log(1/25)
-3.2188758248682006
>>> 1/25
0.04
```